# Align text area from xml file

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to align align my text area from my .swf flash. Directly from xml
I mention that i have actionscript 2.0

My code is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><content>
<!-- general vars -->
<section name="settings">
    <item name="textSelectable">true</item>
    <item name="copyright"><![CDATA[SICURO © 2013 | <font color="#ffffff"><a href="asfunction:_root.more_click_func, privacyPolicy"> PRIVACY POLICY</a></font> 
    ]]></item>
    <item name="companyName"><![CDATA[SICURO<font color="#ff0000">INVEST</font>
    ]]></item>
    <item name="slogan"><![CDATA[Youre SECURITY]]></item>
    <image imageUrl="_logo.png"/>
</section></content>
```

How can i edit `companyName` to align center directly from xml file?

Any idea how can i edit this ? It's look really ugly in my flash document.
I saw in actions in Flash CS5.

```
function getCompanyName(textObj){
textObj.htmlText = getSettingsValue(mainObj, "companyName", "item");
textSelectable(textObj);} // End of the functionfunction getSlogan(textObj){
textObj.htmlText = getSettingsValue(mainObj, "slogan", "item");
textSelectable(textObj);} // End of the function
```

This is what should i edit?

Comment: you set text alignment on the TextField (on the stage) not the xml itself

Answer (score 0):

like someone said, set the alignemnt in the TextField in actionscript rather than editing html in the xml. you would use `textObj.autoSize = "center";`

if you really must do it in the xml, you may use `<center>` tag around the text